# KVO notification with Core Data in Swift

Tags: core-data, key-value-observing

When I generate an NSManagedObject subclass with swift, the property types are all @NSManaged, meaning I can't observe them.  This is a problem when using bindings in a Cocoa application because updating the property frequently requires other properties to be 'updated'.

For example, if I add this method to my NSManagedObject subclass:

```swift
dynamic var ratePerPoint: Double {
    guard pointsPerMonth > 0 else { return 0 }

    return monthlyRate / Double(pointsPerMonth)
}
```

Then it's important that whenever I update the pointsPerMonth variable, which is part of the core data object, that I send a `didChangeValueForKey("ratePerPoint")` message.

If I don't, then the UI bindings don't update properly.

Comment: Core data is (apart from bugs) KVO & KVC compliant, explain what you're doing and what isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ratePerPoint` is a calculated property you have to implement `keyPathsForValuesAffectingRatePerPoint` in your NSManagedObject subclass.

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingRatePerPoint {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"monthlyRate", @"pointsPerMonth", nil];
}
```

Documentation: [Registering Dependent Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE)